# HtmlUnitDriver is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

HtmlUnitDriver is not working properly. Below are the sample code. What am i doing wrong?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;

public class HtmlUnitDriver_Example 
{
    public static HtmlUnitDriver driver = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() 
    {
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11);
        driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test_01()
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to execute Test_01");
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Below two lines are not returning anything meaningful on console.

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Instead, I got the following output;

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--592945208\testng-customsuite.xml

Trying to execute Test_01
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body/>
</html>


PASSED: Test_01

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Please help.

Comment: You are using an old version, please use latest one, which prints the page source plus `Google` as the title

Comment: version of what? I am using Selenium 2.48.2.  If TestNG then yes, I am using an older one, but getting the same result if not using TestNG at all.

Comment: Yes, with Selenium 2.48.2 your test works with me. The only change is that `setUp()` and `tearDown()` must be static

Comment: @AhmedAshour..I think setup() and teardown() must be static only in Junit. It can be non static in TestNG. Please Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @asu... I am getting the output as expected.

Comment: @Striker, yes. It runs fine on other systems but mine. Trying to find out the reason. Thanks.